# String positional parsing in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a long string and, based on some index and length, get that value converted to a specific data type the fastest possible because I need to process about 1000 strings/second. To be clear, I need something like this

```
String initial = "4239898 mdj 8746bbbrts675420120214";

Someclass parser = new Someclass(initial);

Date date = parser.getDate(26,8);
```

So date is parsed using the substring from position 26 to 26+8

So basically, I would like to know if is there already a class which helps me to accomplish this or if any one could suggest some fast algorithm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you very much for your great and fast replies. It seems to do it the old way is the fastest :)

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a really cool "framework" for my purpose. It's called fixedformat4j and it does exactly what I want and with a very fast performance even it's a little old.

Here's the basic example found on its website ( http://fixedformat4j.ancientprogramming.com/ ) :

```
@Record  
public class BasicRecord {  

  private String stringData;  
  private Integer integerData;  
  private Date dateData;  


  @Field(offset = 1, length = 10)  
  public String getStringData() {  
    return stringData;  
  }  

  public void setStringData(String stringData) {  
    this.stringData = stringData;  
  }  

  @Field(offset = 11, length = 5, align = Align.RIGHT, paddingChar = '0')  
  public Integer getIntegerData() {  
    return integerData;  
  }  

  public void setIntegerData(Integer integerData) {  
    this.integerData = integerData;  
  }  

  @Field(offset = 16, length = 10)  
  @FixedFormatPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")  
  public Date getDateData() {  
    return dateData;  
  }  

  public void setDateData(Date dateData) {  
    this.dateData = dateData;  
  }  
}
```

This annotated class can now be loaded and exported using a FixedFormatManager

```
public class BasicUsage {  

  private static FixedFormatManager manager = new FixedFormatManagerImpl();  

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String string = "string    001232008-05-29";  
    BasicRecord record = manager.load(BasicRecord.class, string);  

    System.out.println("The parsed string: " + record.getStringData());  
    System.out.println("The parsed integer: " + record.getIntegerData());  
    System.out.println("The parsed date: " + record.getDateData());  

    record.setIntegerData(100);  
    System.out.println("Exported: " + manager.export(record));  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String []args)  {
        String initial = "4239898 mdj 8746bbbrts675420120214";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date parsed = new Date();

        try {
            parsed = format.parse(initial.substring(26,34));
        }
        catch(ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(parsed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I know of. I don't see how to do it faster than the following:

```
public Date getDate(int start)
{
    int year = Integer.parseInt( initial.substring(start, start + 4) );
    int month = Integer.parseInt( initial.substring(start + 4, start + 6) );
    int day = Integer.parseInt( initial.substring(start + 6, start + 8) );
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```

If all your dates are in the format YYYYMMDD, that's probably faster than using the `SimpleDateFormat` class. (Note that you don't need to pass the length (8) in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting explanation from [this](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html) string article

> StringBuilder class was introduced in JDK 1.5. It is the same as
>   StringBuffer class, except that StringBuilder is not synchronized for
>   multi-thread operations. However, for single-thread program,
>   StringBuilder, without the synchronization overhead, is more
>   efficient.
>
> Rule of Thumb: Strings are more efficient if they are not modified
>   (because they are shared in the string common pool). However, if you
>   have to modify the content of a string frequently (such as a status
>   message), you should use the StringBuffer class (or the StringBuilder
>   described below) instead.

So you can probably experiment with these two classes or the default String class. Decide which one works best in your situation. I have the following class which give about 300ms under *extremely* heavy loaded system.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class StringEfficientParser
{

    //String initial = "4239898 mdj 8746bbbrts675420120214";
    public static void parseString(String input) throws ParseException
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
        String input_date = sb.substring(26, 34);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
        Date date = sdf.parse(input_date);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            parseString("4239898 mdj 8746bbbrts675420120214");          
        }
        long stop  = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("elapsed time : " + (stop - start));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thak for your answer. It seems StringBuilder is realy faster than String. :)